# What are the ideas behind Trotters proof of the Central Limit theorem

Tags: central-limit-theorem

We recently did Trotters proof of the central limit theorem and all I can see in the proof is just a lot of calculus and inequalities and I don`t really understand the ideas behind the proof. Can someone give a rough sketch of the ideas that are used in the proof?

Comment: The Springer web site displays a [preview of Trotter's paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01240790).  Its first page is devoted to answering your question.